# What is the role of Mandelstam variables in strings theory

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory

What is the role of [Mandelstam variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelstam_variables) in strings theory?

What is relationship between [Mandelstam variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelstam_variables) and [Veneziano amplitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veneziano_amplitude)?

Answer (score 3):

Mandelstam variables represent $s,t,u$ Lorentz-invariant quantities, corresponding to different "channels" of interaction.

So, they are not connected to a particular theory.

In string theory, the particularity is that you cannot distinguish the different channels. For instance, if you study open string amplitude or closed string amplitude for $4$ tachyons, you get amplitudes as functions of $s,t,u$, and you may exchange 2 of the $3$ channels, for instance $s \leftrightarrow t$, while leaving invariant the amplitude.

The $4$-tachyon open string amplitude could be written : $A_4(s,t,u) = V(s,t) + V(s,u)+V(t,u)$, where $V(x,y)$ is the (symmetric) Veneziano amplitude.